# Is it possible to have different amount of features for the Classification decision in a support vector machine?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

Is it possible to train a support vector machine with two classes using two features and then trying to make a decision for a new data object to which class it belongs that has the same two features plus one more feature. Would this change the space the support vector machine makes the decision or will the third feature be ignored and only the other two are considered?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on tools. I guess in the most cases it will raise error. The input shape of data should be exactly the same as train data shape. It's impossible that a SVM  model use a feature that it hasn't seen.

Comment: Would it be possible if the SVM is unable to decide to which class the new data object belongs(by raising an error message), because of the third feature, to create a new class? And additional data objects with the same third feature could then be matched to this new class.  So for visualization purpose, you could introduce a new green dot besides the blue and red dots for instance.